# Data storing in wrong field in firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, user-input

`enter code here` I have a registration form in android application where user can enter their details. And i try to store data into firebase, the data are storing but the problem is in phone number  age will store, in age field name will  store. How to solve this issue? Please help!

Helperclass

public class UserHelperClass {

```
String fullName, city, age, disease, gender, bloodGroup, password, phoneNumber;

 public UserHelperClass() {
}

public UserHelperClass(String fullName, String city, String age, String disease, String gender, String bloodGroup, String password, String phoneNumber) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.city = city;
    this.age = age;
    this.disease = disease;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.bloodGroup = bloodGroup;
    this.password = password;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getDisease() {
    return disease;
}

public void setDisease(String disease) {
    this.disease = disease;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getBloodGroup() {
    return bloodGroup;
}

public void setBloodGroup(String bloodGroup) {
    this.bloodGroup = bloodGroup;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
```

}

data storing to firebase code

```
    rootNode=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    reference=rootNode.getReference("Users");

    UserHelperClass helperClass=new UserHelperClass(fullName,city,age,phoneNumber,bloodGroup,age,disease,password);

    reference.child(phoneNumber).setValue(helperClass);
```

geting data from another activity

```
phoneNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("keynumber");
    fullName = getIntent().getStringExtra("keyname");
    city = getIntent().getStringExtra("keycity");
    age = getIntent().getStringExtra("keyage");
    disease = getIntent().getStringExtra("keydisease");
    bloodGroup = getIntent().getStringExtra("keybloodgroup");
    gender = getIntent().getStringExtra("keygender");
    password = getIntent().getStringExtra("keypassword");
```

pass data to another activity

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private AutoCompleteTextView dropDownText;
TextView titletext;
TextView chooegender;
TextView selectage;
TextInputLayout fullname, city, number, disease, password, bloodgroup;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton selectedGender, radio1, radio2, radio3;
DatePicker datePicker;
CountryCodePicker countryCodePicker;
Button registerbtn;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);


    dropDownText = findViewById(R.id.dropdown_text);
    titletext = findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    chooegender = findViewById(R.id.choose_gender);
    selectage = findViewById(R.id.select_age);
    fullname = findViewById(R.id.name);
    city = findViewById(R.id.city);
    number = findViewById(R.id.number);
    countryCodePicker = findViewById(R.id.country_code_picker);
    disease = findViewById(R.id.disease);
    bloodgroup = findViewById(R.id.bloodgroup);
    password = findViewById(R.id.password);

    radio1 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    radio2 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
    radio3 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);

    radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    datePicker = findViewById(R.id.age_picker);
    selectedGender = findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    registerbtn = findViewById(R.id.register);



    String[] item = new String[]{
            "A+Ve",
            "A-Ve",
            "B+Ve",
            "B-Ve",
            "AB+Ve",
            "AB-Ve",
            "O+Ve",
            "O-Ve"

    };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            RegisterActivity.this,
            R.layout.dropdown_item,
            item
    );
    dropDownText.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void callotpverificationscreen(View view) {
    if (!validateFullname() | !validateCity() | !validateDisease() | !validateNumber() | !validatePassword() | !validateGender() | !validateAge())
        return;

    selectedGender = findViewById(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    String _gender = selectedGender.getText().toString().trim();

    int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
    int month = datePicker.getMonth();
    int year = datePicker.getYear();

    String Age = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
    String FullName = fullname.getEditText().getText().toString();
    String City = city.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
    String Disease = disease.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
    String Blood_group = bloodgroup.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
    String code = countryCodePicker.getSelectedCountryCodeWithPlus();
    String Number = number.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
    String CompletePhoneNumber = "+" + countryCodePicker.getFullNumber() + Number;
    String Password = password.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();


    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OTP_verification.class);
    intent.putExtra("keyname", FullName);
    intent.putExtra("keycity", City);
    intent.putExtra("keyage", Age);
    intent.putExtra("keydisease", Disease);
    intent.putExtra("keybloodgroup", Blood_group);
    intent.putExtra("keynumber", CompletePhoneNumber);
    intent.putExtra("keypassword", Password);
    intent.putExtra("keygender", _gender);
    startActivity(intent);


}
```

Firebase database image(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYoYt.jpg)

Comment: Please provide your code and an example of your Firebase structure.

Comment: @AdrianRusso check it

Comment: Is the data stored incorrectly in Firebase? If so, could you provide a picture of your Firebase console?

Comment: Yes exactly data  are store incorrectly. You got it..

Comment: @AdrianRusso i have added a picture of firebase console check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting the Strings in the wrong order when creating a new UserHelperClass. So:

```
UserHelperClass helperClass = new UserHelperClass(fullName, city, age, disease, gender, bloodGroup, password, phoneNumber);
```

instead of

```
UserHelperClass helperClass = new UserHelperClass(fullName,city,age,phoneNumber,bloodGroup,age,disease,password);
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't followed the correct order like UserHelperClass:
You should follow this format:

```
fullName, city, age, disease, gender, bloodGroup, password, phoneNumber
```

But you have used wrong order when calling class.
Use this format

```
    UserHelperClass helperClass=new UserHelperClass(fullName, city, age, disease, gender, bloodGroup, password, phoneNumber);
```

In-spite of this:

```
    UserHelperClass helperClass=new UserHelperClass(fullName,city,age,phoneNumber,bloodGroup,age,disease,password);
```